# Java - Chess Game using MouseAdapter for mouse clicks to move a piece

Tags: java, events, mouseevent, mouselistener

Im creating the classic game of chess, and have implemented a board, and I've created a abstract piece class, which the other pieces extend. I have created a Pawn class, which I am trying to implement and test moving the pawn. I have created an inner class that extends mouse adapter and overrides the `mouseClicked()` method. I have it printing 1 to the console to ensure it works. The requirement is to click on a "source" piece, and then click on a destination and the piece should move to the destination, as long as it's within the boundaries of the board.

I am wondering if I have placed my mouse listener in the correct area, and if so, if the mouseClicked method is executed each time a mouse click event happens, how can you remember the piece that was clicked as source, in order to move it to the destination where you click.

The board is made up of background objects, a background object is simply just a "black" or "white" square image that draws itself, board is made up of an 8 x 8 grid of the background objects. The code is below:

Background.java

```
    /*
     * Displays a single image of a background
    */

    import java.awt.Graphics2D; 
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.File;

    public class BackGround {

       private BufferedImage image;
       private int x,y;

       public BackGround(String imageName, int x, int y) {
          this.x = x;
            this.y = y;

            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(new File(imageName));

            } catch  (IOException e) {}
        }

       public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
            g.drawImage(image, x, y, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);  
        } 
    }
```

Board.java

```
/*
 * Displays a board
*/

import java.awt.Graphics2D; 
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Board {

   private Piece[][] pieces;
   private BackGround[][] theBackGround;
   private int ROW_SIZE;
   private int COL_SIZE;
   private int xPos = 220;
   private int yPos = 220;
   final protected static String IMG_BG_BLACK = "image/black.PNG";
   final protected static String IMG_BG_WHITE = "image/white.PNG";

   public Board(final int ROW_SIZE, final int COL_SIZE) {
      this.ROW_SIZE = ROW_SIZE;
      this.COL_SIZE = COL_SIZE;

      pieces = new Piece[ROW_SIZE][COL_SIZE];

      for(int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++) {
          for(int j = 0; j < COL_SIZE; j++) {
             pieces[i][j] = new DummyPiece();
          }
      }

      theBackGround = new BackGround[ROW_SIZE][COL_SIZE];

      for(int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++) {
         for(int j = 0; j < COL_SIZE; j++) {
            if(i % 2 == 0){
               if(j % 2 == 0){
                  theBackGround[i][j] = new BackGround(IMG_BG_BLACK, xPos, yPos);
               }
               else 
                  theBackGround[i][j] = new BackGround(IMG_BG_WHITE, xPos, yPos);
            }
            if(i % 2 == 1){
               if(j % 2 == 1){
                  theBackGround[i][j] = new BackGround(IMG_BG_BLACK, xPos, yPos);
               }
               else 
                  theBackGround[i][j] = new BackGround(IMG_BG_WHITE, xPos, yPos);
            }
         xPos += 45; 
         }
      xPos = 220;
      yPos += 45; 
      } 
   }

   // Ask each background to print itself
   public void paint(Graphics g){

      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

      for(int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++) {
         for(int j = 0; j < COL_SIZE; j++) {
            theBackGround[i][j].paint(g2);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Piece.java

```
//All pieces will inherit from this class
public abstract class Piece {

   protected String color;
   protected String type;
   protected int posR;
   protected int posC;
   protected BufferedImage image;

   abstract public void paint(Graphics2D g2);

   abstract public String getType();

   abstract public String getColor();

   /*
    This piece can report it's current row
    @return int the pieces current row
   */
   public int getRowPos() {
      return this.posR;
   }

   /*
    This piece can report it's current column
    @return int the pieces current column
   */
   public int getColPos() {
      return this.posC;
   }

   /*
    Sets a new position for this piece
    @param x the new row position for this piece
    @param y the new column position for this piece
   */
   public void setPos(int x, int y) {
      posR = x;
      posC = y;
   }

}
```

Pawn.java

```
//Inherits from abstract Piece
public class Pawn extends Piece {

   public Pawn(String imageName, String color, int x, int y) {
      this.posR = x;
        this.posC = y;
      this.type = "PAWN";
        this.color = color;
        try {
            this.image = ImageIO.read(new File(imageName));

        } catch  (IOException e) {}
    }

   public String getType() {
      return this.type;
   }

   public String getColor() {
      return this.color;
   }

   public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
        g.drawImage(image, this.posR, this.posC, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);  
    }      
}
```

ChessBoard.java

```
public class ChessBoard extends Board {

      final private static String IMG_PAWNB = "image/bP.PNG";
      final private static String IMG_PAWNW = "image/wP.PNG";

      private Pawn pawn;

      public ChessBoard() {
         super(8, 8);
         pawn = new Pawn(IMG_PAWNB, "BLACK", 310, 265);
      }

      public void paint(Graphics g){
         super.paint(g);
         Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
         pawn.paint(g2);
      }
}
```

ChessViewer.java

```
public class ChessViewer extends JComponent {

   private ChessBoard chessBoard;

    public ChessViewer() {
        chessBoard = new ChessBoard();
      addMouseListener(new MouseClickListener());
    }

   public void paint(Graphics h) {
        chessBoard.paint(h);  
    }

   class MouseClickListener extends MouseAdapter {
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event){
          System.out.println("1");
      }
   }

}
```

ChessRunner.java(Tester)

```
public class ChessRunner {

   private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 800;
   private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 800;

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      JFrame frame = new JFrame();

      frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
      frame.setTitle("Chess");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      ChessViewer component = new ChessViewer();
      frame.add(component);

      frame.setVisible(true);  
   }

}
```

Comment: Yes, your `mouseListener` is in the right place (or at least on the right component).  You need to convert the mouse point from the screen coordinates to the game/board coordinates so you can ascertain the cell that the user clicked.  From there, you need to obtain a reference to the `Piece` which occupies that location (if there is one).  This will allow you to determine which `Piece` to move on the next click as well as the location to move it to

Comment: @MadProgrammer I created some methods which returns the piece or cell where the user clicked, but I still don't understand how to anticipate where the next click is going to be. In the mouseClicked method, I am repainting the images on each click after setting the new position for the piece but it just keeps over writing it's own position because I can only set the piece to the location of where the user has clicked, and I don't know where that is until it happens.

Comment: Basically you can only deal with the current state, if when `mouseClicked` occurs, there is no selected piece AND the cell contains a piece, then you select it.  If their is a selected piece, you need to determine if the move is valid based on the rules you are implementing

Comment: I implemented what you are saying, and it's now working. Thank you.